# RubyMine NodeJS Custom Modules Code Completion

Tags: node.js, rubymine, code-completion, node-modules

I can get RubyMine to do code completion of NodeJS core modules.  However, I can't seem to get it to do code completion on the custom modules in the `node_modules` directory of my project.  I tried adding the directory as a javascript library, but no dice.  I've only been able to find posts about code completion of the core modules but nothing that makes mention of custom modules.  Any thoughts?